# {@inheritdoc} causing phpstorm to ignore all other tags

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I have the following documentation:

```
/**
     * Creates a Mortgage account
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @param string $closingDate the date from which the mortgage starts accumulating interest and payments begin.
     */
    function __construct($principle,$term,$interest,$compoundFrequency,$amortization,$closingDate)
    {
        parent::__construct($principle,$term,$interest,$compoundFrequency,$amortization);

    }
```

When I ctrl+Q in phpstorm for the quickdoc i get the following
[image]

My additional documentation seems to be completely ignored.

Is it possible to have the parent documentation as well as the additional child info display in phpstorm when using ctrl+Q ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have the parent documentation as well as the additional child info display in phpstorm when using ctrl+Q ?

Unfortunately not (there is no separate options for that or anything like that).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23395 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

Accordingly to the ticket status it is planned to be resolved in PhpStorm v9.